# Allow specific user to view SharePoint documents (minor versions) / Create file with specific user 'Created By'

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate, flow

A document has been created by flow in SharePoint Online and 'Created By' is the set to the flow Owner. Unfortunately, the flow action does not allow me to set the 'Created By' to a specific user.
Approval's are enabled, creating minor version.

The issue is that the person who uploaded the file (via Power App > Flow) is not the 'Created By' of the document and as a result cannot see the document as it's a minor version.

If I adjust the permissions to Design then the user has access to the minor version. However when submitted for approval, Design permissions need to remain which means the user can approve his/her own document.
Is there a way to either:

1. Create a file in Flow which sets the Created By user who
   submitted file or
2. Allow this specific user to see this draft
   file only?

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Created By column value to respective user using Power automate flow.

Follow the steps:

1. Pass email address of current user to Power automate flow
2. Get loginName (user principal name) of user from Office 365 users connector **OR** generate the loginName using email in format like:

   ```
   i:0#.f|membership|meganB@contoso.onmicrosoft.com
   ```
3. Then use flow like below:

   [image]

**Flow action configurations**:

**Compose User**:

```
[
  {
    "Key": "i:0#.f|membership|meganB@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
  }
]
```

**2nd Compose - formValues**:

```
[
  {
    "FieldName": "Author",
    "FieldValue": "@{outputs('Compose_User')}"
  }
]
```

**Send an HTTP request to SharePoint**:

**Method**: `POST`

**Uri**:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ViewThreshold')/items(1)/validateUpdateListItem
```

Use list name and item ID as per your SharePoint site.

**Body**:

```
{
   "formValues": @{outputs('2nd Compose - formValues')},
   "bNewDocumentUpdate": true
}
```

Comment: I'm sure I tried this and it wouldn't work. Reading further, I found it only works for Lists. Have you tried it for a library?

Comment: I haven't tried with a library yet. You are running flow via Power Apps, right? Ideally when you run flow via Power apps, it runs with the context of current user in app - so why file is not created using app user instead of flow owner? which actions and connections are you using to create file.

Comment: PowerApps runs under user context. The Flow is of of Instant type and I'm using a PowerApps trigger in the flow.

Comment: Which actions are you using to create file? If flow is running in context of user and same flow is creating a file, ideally Created By should user who is running flow from app.

Comment: Using 'Create File' action. I believe the flow runs under the owner account. This is because of the PowerApp's trigger thats being used in the flow.

Comment: I'm using the PowerApps V2 trigger in the flow, and passing some parameters from the App to the flow.

Comment: Can you check if these settings are correct for the connection you are using for creating file: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Update-the-child-flow-for-action-Run-a-Child-Flow-to-not-use-run/m-p/789709/highlight/true#M109832. For your scenario, connection should be **Provided by run-only user**.

Comment: I think its not the flow but the PowerApp as I created a new App without a flow and have similar problem. When End User open an app for the first time, a permissions dialog is displayed. For the problem user, the default account setting is not the user but the account the SP data source is using. However for another user, it is the user account. Where are this information being stored  and how is it selected?

Comment: Check if you can find it in **Connections** section in Power Apps portal for those user accounts.