# Update moderation status (Approval)

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, power-automate

I want to update the Moderation Status of a Document (minor version enabled) from Pending to Approved or Rejected without affecting the Modified By column. I have tried ootb flow Action 'Set Content Approval Status', though this updated the status it also updated the Modified By column, so this is no good. Therefore, I'm trying CSOM but I cannot get this to update the status at all. Is there a mistake with the following?
I've tried various headers but still not working.

[image]

```
    {
  "Content-Type": "text/xml;charset=\"UTF-8\"",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHTTPRequest",
  "Accept": "*/*"
}

<Request xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="16.0.0.0" ApplicationName="Javascript Library">
    <Actions>
        <Method Name="SetFieldValue" Id="4" ObjectPathId="3">
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Type="String">_ModerationStatus</Parameter>
                 <Parameter Type="String">0</Parameter>
</Parameters>
        </Method>
        <Method Name="SystemUpdate" Id="5" ObjectPathId="3" />
    </Actions>
    <ObjectPaths>
        <Property Id="1" ParentId="0" Name="Web" />
        <Method Id="2" ParentId="1" Name="GetList">
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Type="String">@{variables('libraryPath')}</Parameter>
            </Parameters>
        </Method>
        <Method Id="3" ParentId="2" Name="GetItemById">
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Type="Number">@{triggerBody()?['entity']?['ID']}</Parameter>
            </Parameters>
        </Method>
        <StaticProperty Id="0" TypeId="{3747adcd-a3c3-41b9-bfab-4a64dd2f1e0a}" Name="Current" />
    </ObjectPaths>
</Request>
```

There are no errors reported when thisaction runs.   "ErrorInfo": null

Comment: Use `ValidateUpdateListItem` API instead of above approach. Check this: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/update-file-metadata-with-rest-api-using-validateupdatelistitem/ba-p/1365682. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Check my answer here to know how to use it in flow: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306699/allow-specific-user-to-view-sharepoint-documents-minor-versions-create-file/306700#306700. You can use Editor field instead of Author field > update it with existing user in "Modified By" column.

Comment: You can also use PowerShell to do such updates if not limited to using Power automate only.

Comment: ValidateUpdateListItem only workd for lists and Im using a document library. I can only use PowerAutomate to perform this task. 
All I wish to do is update the ModerationStatus without affecting the ModifiedBy Column